# I can't understand what Maven is. I've red a lot about it but still don't get it

Tags: java, maven

It says Maven is a build tool. Is it like an IDE? Well what is 'building'? What do you mean by it?

Assume you want to write a java code. You open up Eclipse, you write your class, then you export it to a JAR file and everyone uses it. Is this called building? If yes then why do you need Maven?

It also says it manages your dependencies. Well If i'm writing a class that needs dependencies, I should already know what they are and import them shouldn't I?

Please help my understand what is Maven ad what can it do that Eclipse can't do? And please don't keep saying 'It's a build tool'

Comment: It's a build tool which managers diverse and large dependency trees. *"If i'm writing a class that needs dependencies, I should already know what they are and import them shouldn't I?"* - But if you didn't write it?  I can tell you after 15+ years of writing code, I can't remember ALL the dependencies my libraries require OR manage the up-grade process as new releases of libraries are released.  Maven can allow you to customise the build process independently of the IDE, it can manage changes in the dependency change and just generally makes life SO much easier

Comment: It's a highly flexible command-line build tool. You feed it a bunch of source files and a set of rules, and it invokes various programs (compilers, linkers, etc.) to convert your sources to compiled artifacts (jars, wars, ears, DLLs, etc.) It also downloads dependencies on demand. But it is a build tool nevertheless.

Comment: what do you by a build tool, what is 'building'?

Comment: @genericMetal "Building" is making whatever files you want (JAR files probably) out of whatever files you have (Java files, library JAR files, configuration files...)

Comment: Eclipse can already do that perfectly tho.

Comment: @genericMetal You project (the source code), it will, if you configure it to, generate a fat jar (merging all the dependencies into a single Jar), or organise all the dependencies into a common location and update the jar's manifest, but the real power is in it's ability to identify and manage a diverse dependency tree. If you've every used ANY Apache libraries, you'll know what a headache that can be

Comment: @genericMetal *"Eclipse can already do that perfectly tho"* - based on what your needs are, probably, but as your projects become more complex and have large dependency graph or require a customised build process, it begins to fall down (yes, Ant is very customisable, but it falls down on the dependency management). If you can't see a need for Maven, then you don't yet have a need for maven, but as person who would rather spend time coding then downloading and linking in a bunch of diverse library dependencies, I'll use it :P

Answer (score 2):

According to the [What maven is?](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/introduction-sect-whatIsMaven.html) section in [this complete reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/).

> A more formal definition of Apache Maven: Maven is a project management tool which encompasses a project object model, a set of standards, a project lifecycle, a dependency management system, and logic for executing plugin goals at defined phases in a lifecycle. When you use Maven, you describe your project using a well-defined project object model, Maven can then apply cross-cutting logic from a set of shared (or custom) plugins.

Now this article says a *Project Management Tool*.. What that is? Well if you read the first paragraph.

> Build engineers and project managers might refer to Maven as something more comprehensive: a project management tool. What is the difference? A build tool such as Ant is focused solely on preprocessing, compilation, packaging, testing, and distribution. A project management tool such as Maven provides a superset of features found in a build tool. In addition to providing build capabilities, Maven can also run reports, generate a web site, and facilitate communication among members of a working team.

So being a project management tool these are the things maven can do for you

1. **Create Project Structure** : Most of the time you may not know what should be the correct project structure. Just choose a correct maven archetype and you are good to go.
2. **Resolve Dependencies** : Here I'll try to answer your *Well If i'm writing a class that needs dependencies, I should already know what they are and import them shouldn't I?*  No.. not really!

   Have you ever used a framework and added all its required jars AKA dependencies to your calsspath such that you get no compilation errors yet at runtime you get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`? A common example is when you use `spring` you also need `commons-logging.jar`but its not bundled together when you download spring distribution. Most of the times one dependency depends on another and those on yet another. Its not possible for a developer to know about them all but maven does. So if you use maven you never search google for `java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org/slf4j/loggerfactory jar` and the download and add it to classpath.

As pointed out in the comments, to resolve dependencies using maven  repositories are required. If you dont't add one, you have [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) by default where maven will look to download the dependencies. Apart from central repositories, you also have a local repository `.m2` folder in home directory. So if dependencies are once downloaded and available locally, they won't be downloaded again. 
If you need dependencies exclusive to your organisation, you need to add the repository url and of course have access to it.

3. **Testing** : If you follow certain standards and write unit tests, maven will automatically execute all your unit tests and show the results. It won't let you package your project unless all tests are successful by default.
4. **Package** : Maven will export your project to `jar` / `war` or `ear` depending on your project archetype.
5. **Deployment** : Maven can also do the deployment for you. See [here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-common-goals.html#lifecycle-sect-deploy-phase).

You can do all this without the need to an IDE just with a command line.

But almost every time you have an IDE and some of these tasks are also supported by IDEs out of the box. Okay use maven just for dependency management. I personally feel its the best feature and use it only because I again can't go through the pain of `NoClassDefFoundError` and then search google for jars for hours.

Comment: How does Maven know dependency of every project on earth, maybe the dependency is  JAR file that google owns and only google employees can use, how's Maven going to know about it? Maven has it's own servers  that keeps all these JAR files?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it like an IDE?

No its not. (You may get irritated listening but yes its Build tool, why? check below)

> Well what is 'building'?

- Building is bringing all artifacts(classes,resources,xmls,jsons,etc) together and introduce them to each other. So that they can work together to fulfill their goals.
- Also Maven has a structure, Like test classes goes in particular folder, Test resource in particular folder, java source classes in particular folder, and so on you can check it.

  This has advantage, When we deploy our project like on jenkins it knows where to find test classes, where to find test resources, where to find configuration files and many more locations.

When we are talking about huge project there are many things to configure and without built tool this well be a big mess.

> Well If i'm writing a class that needs dependencies, I should already know what they are and import them shouldn't I?

Say you have dependency of 100 jars and you need to update them after few days,
You will go on downloading each jar online and add it manually to your code.

Also you will circulate your project with this 100 jars with other members who will be working on your project.

Thats cumbersome...

With Maven, just edit the POM for version which you want and it will be downloaded from central repository. Else add it to your local repo.

> You open up Eclipse, you write your class, then you export it to a JAR file and everyone uses it. Is this called building?

Yes it is.

> If yes then why do you need Maven?

Again same theory, you are working on big project with 5 custom jars and you have team members in India,japan,US all working in collaboration. With above theory you can imagine what problems you will have to face.

I hope you got the gist of what actually maven is.

Comment: How does Maven know dependency of every project on earth, maybe the dependency is JAR file that google owns and only google employees can use, how's Maven going to know about it? Maven has it's own servers that keeps all these JAR files?

Comment: Expected this question, yes maven dont understand custom jars but we can tell him to understand it, how? check this link https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: @genericMetal I tried to give you a high level understanding of maven, which even I was confused when started studying. But believe me its beautiful this splace is too small to explain everthing. i recommend stduying docs

Comment: sounds like maven is for huge projects with many dependencies. But it's pointless if my project has 10 classes and needs 5 dependencies, right? Also if big companies use Maven, can they have their own repositories so their stuff doesn't get uploaded to public?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/ it has almost all standard jars in world. No matter 5 or 100, its just like maintaining a sort of standard, directory structure and all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from javascript background, `Maven` is similar to `npm`. When you are using npm, npm reads `package.json` to download the dependencies and in Maven,it reads `pom.xml`.